# How do I use numpy.where()? What should I pass, and what does the result mean?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I tried reading the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `numpy.where()`, but I'm still confused.

What should I pass for the `condition`, `x` and `y` values? When I pass only `condition`, what does the result mean and how can I use it? What about when I pass all three?

I found [How does python numpy.where() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642457) but it didn't answer my question because it seems to be about the implementation rather than about how to use it. [Numpy where() on a 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219841) also didn't explain things for me; I'm looking for a step-by-step explanation, rather than a how-to guide for a specific case.

Please include examples with both 1D and 2D source data.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

After fiddling around for a while, I figured things out, and am posting them here hoping it will help others.

Intuitively, `np.where` is like asking "*tell me where in this array, entries satisfy a given condition*".

```
>>> a = np.arange(5,10)
>>> np.where(a < 8)       # tell me where in a, entries are < 8
(array([0, 1, 2]),)       # answer: entries indexed by 0, 1, 2
```

It can also be used to get entries in array that satisfy the condition:

```
>>> a[np.where(a < 8)] 
array([5, 6, 7])          # selects from a entries 0, 1, 2
```

---

When `a` is a 2d array, `np.where()` returns an array of row idx's, and an array of col idx's:

```
>>> a = np.arange(4,10).reshape(2,3)
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.where(a > 8)
(array(1), array(2))
```

As in the 1d case, we can use `np.where()` to get entries in the 2d array that satisfy the condition:

```
>>> a[np.where(a > 8)] # selects from a entries 0, 1, 2
```

array([9])

---

Note, when `a` is 1d, `np.where()` still returns an array of row idx's and an array of col idx's, but columns are of length 1, so latter is empty array.

Comment: I was struggling on understanding np.where when used on 2d until I found your answer "When a is a 2d array, np.where() returns an array of row idx's, and an array of col idx's:". Thanks for that.

Comment: I was feeling pretty stupid after reading the doc three times and still not solving the puzzle `np.where(2d_array)`, thanks for clearing this up! You should accept your own answer. e: Oh, it's closed. Well, it shouldn't be

Comment: It's a shame this was closed. However I would like to add another feature of `np.where` to this otherwise complete answer. The function can also select elements from the x and y array depending on the condition. Limited space in this comment but see: `np.where(np.array([[False,False,True],
                   [True,False,False]]),
         np.array([[8,2,6],
                   [9,5,0]]),
         np.array([[4,8,7],
                   [3,2,1]]))` will return `array([[4, 8, 6],
       [9, 2, 1]])`.  Notice which elements of x and y get chosen depending on True/False

Comment: The explanation given in this answer is only a special case of np.where. According to the documentation, When only `condition` is provided, this function is a shorthand for
        ``np.asarray(condition).nonzero()``.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a little more fun. I've found that very often NumPy does exactly what I wish it would do - sometimes it's faster for me to just try things than it is to read the docs. Actually a mixture of both is best.

I think your answer is fine (and it's OK to accept it if you like). This is just "extra".

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(4,10).reshape(2,3)

wh = np.where(a>7)
gt = a>7
x  = np.where(gt)

print "wh: ", wh
print "gt: ", gt
print "x:  ", x
```

gives:

```
wh:  (array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]))
gt:  [[False False False]
      [False  True  True]]
x:   (array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]))
```

... but:

```
print "a[wh]: ", a[wh]
print "a[gt]  ", a[gt]
print "a[x]:  ", a[x]
```

gives:

```
a[wh]:  [8 9]
a[gt]   [8 9]
a[x]:   [8 9]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649568/use-of-np-where0