# How to NaN elements in a numpy array based on upper and lower boundery

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an numpy array with 0-10 elements.

```
a = np.arange(0,11)
np.random.shuffle(a)
a
array([ 1,  7,  8,  0,  2,  3,  4, 10,  9,  5,  6])
```

I wanted to convert elements to NaN if they are between 4 and 8.
As a first step I tried getting the array with `np.where` like below:

```
np.where([a > 4] & [a < 8])
```

but got error. any help please?

Comment: Why >10? Shouldn't that be < 8? Also use rund brackets around `a > 4` not square ones.

Comment: that was by mistake and i have updated the questions. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.arange(0,11)
np.random.shuffle(a)

print(a)
# [ 7  4  2  3  6 10  1  9  5  0  8]

a = np.where((a > 4) & (a < 8), np.nan, a)

print(a)
# [nan  4.  2.  3. nan 10.  1.  9. nan  0.  8.]
```

If you want to know how `np.where()`works, refer [numpy.where() detailed, step-by-step explanation / examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667282/numpy-where-detailed-step-by-step-explanation-examples)