# Use of np.where()[0]

Tags: python, numpy

My code detects all the points under a threshold, then locates the start and end points.

```
below = np.where(self.data < self.threshold)[0]


startandend = np.diff(below)
startpoints = np.insert(startandend, 0, 2)
endpoints = np.insert(startandend, -1, 2)
startpoints = np.where(startpoints>1)[0]
endpoints = np.where(endpoints>1)[0]
startpoints = below[startpoints]
endpoints = below[endpoints]
```

I don't really get the use of [0] after np.where() function here

Comment: Try `print(below)` with and without `[0]` and see the difference. These kind of things you can investigate yourself easily enough

Answer (score 1):

```
below = np.where(self.data < self.threshold)[0]
```

means:

> take the first element from the tuple of ndarrays returned by np.where() and
>   assign it to `below`.

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` is tricky. It returns an **array of lists** of indices where the conditions are met, *even if the condition is never satisfied.* In the case of `np.where(my_numpy_array==some_value)[0]` specifically, this means that you want the first value in the array, which is a list, and which contains the list of indices of condition-meeting cells.

Quite a mouthful. In simple terms, `np.where(array==x)[0]` returns a list of indices where the conditions have been met. I'm guessing this is a result of designing numpy for extensively broad applications.

Keep in mind that no matches *still returns an empty list*; errors like `only size-1 arrays can be converted to python (some type)` may be attributed to that.