# How to mapping using treshold in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
Id  WO
1   56
2   23
3    0
```

My rule is simple, if WO at least 1 give label 1, if less give 0, here's my expected output

```
Id  WO  Label
1   56  1
2   23  1
3    0  0
```

Here's my code

```
import math
due_table_2['Label'] = due_table_2.apply(math.ceil(due_table_2['WO ']/1000))
```

the error message

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy.where() detailed, step-by-step explanation / examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667282/numpy-where-detailed-step-by-step-explanation-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `math.ceil()` doesn't accept Series type variable. You can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```py
due_table_2['Label'] = np.where(due_table_2['WO '] >= 1, 1, 0)
```

Or just convert boolean to int with

```py
due_table_2['Lable'] = (due_table_2['WO '] >= 1).astype(int)
```